# Is Java formatting transferable to writing files?

Tags: java, java-io, printwriter

Sorry for the vague title. What I have is a program which basically takes user input then prints it to a file. Pretty simple. The input consists of a memo title and a subsequent memo to be filed under that title. Between the two there will be a date stamp.

The code I have for printing the file looks like this:

```
System.out.println("Memo topic (enter -1 to end):");
String message = console.nextLine();
now = new Date();
String dateStamp = now.toString();
out.println(topic + "\n" + dateStamp + "\n" + message);
```

out is the name of a PrintWriter I create earlier in the program. The console displays the instructions and takes the input then write them to a file. When I read the text in the file it all runs together and looks like this:

```
ThanksgivingWed Nov 4 14:39:36 CST"Pick up some turkey at the Kroger, you
lazy bum!" said Mom.
```

However, if I change the output to just print to the console, the line break characters actually work and the three pieces of the output string are divided by line. How do I modify this to work correctly as output to a file?

Comment: Are you opening your final file in Notepad ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a plain text file opened in notepad on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're testing this on Windows. That would cause a problem, because on Windows, new lines are represented by `\r\n` (carriage return, line feed), and not all applications will happily accept just the `\n`.

In order to get a system-agnostic line separator, you should use [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) instead, which

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns the same value - the initial value of the system property line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

So your code would become this:

```
out.println(topic + System.lineSeparator() + dateStamp + System.lineSeparator() + message);
```

Comment: Thank you. So lineSeparator() itself determines which character to use depending on the system it is being run on? If I ran this same code on another machine, it would automatically decide the appropriate separator?

Comment: @JoeSchmuck Yep. Its purpose is so that you don't need to worry about it at all. At runtime, it will return the correct value based on where it's running.